# syntax for using head with filename stored in variable

Tags: bash, head

I'm trying to store the first 5 lines from a file in the variable `url`.  But I get an error

```
-n5: command not found
```

`fn_all_urls` stores the path to the file `/home/urls.txt`

My Line is:

```
url=head -n5 ${fn_all_urls} #get first 5 lines in file
echo "$url"
```

I'm using bash on Ubuntu 18.04 64 bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not performing a *command substitution*, which is how you assign the output of a command to a variable. The proper syntax to accomplish this is:

```
url=$(head -n5 "${fn_all_urls}")
```